# Flutter int value if first digit is not zero I want to get first value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Flutter int value if first digit is not zero I want to get first value

for example

int x=123
result =1;

another example
int y=234;
result=2;

if the first value is zero I want to get the second value

for example
int a=023;
result=2;

another example
int b=098;
result=9;

how can i do this using dart?

Answer (score 0):

There surely is a more mathematical way, but one way to do this is to convert the `int` to a `String`, get the first character and parse it back to `int` :

```
var numbers = [
    1234,
    567,
    89,
  ];
  for(var number in numbers) {
    var firstNumber = int.parse(number.toString()[0]);
    print(firstNumber);
  }
```

Output :

```
1
5
8
```

Comment: if the first digit of the number is 0, then it will not return second digit and so on

Comment: I don't get the point with the leading 0. Assign 00048 to an `int` and the value will really be 48. There could be an infinite amount of 0 before. And also after the decimal for a `double` (48,000...).

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the first non-zero digit. Assuming you get your number as a `String`. Otherwise it is pointless because the `int value = 0123` is the same as `int value = 123`.

```
  String yourNumber = "0123";
  final firstNonZero = int.tryParse(yourNumber.split('').firstWhere((element) => element != '0', orElse: () => ''));
  print(firstNonZero);
```